# java - can't break from do-while loop properly

Tags: java, loops

I need to create a program that asks for numbers until the user inserts a zero and after that it should print an average of the inserted numbers. But I'm only able to get average of the first input but not the latter ones.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      double a = 0;
      int b = 0; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        b++;
         System.out.println("insert a number");
          a += input.nextDouble();

    }
    while (a > 0 );{

      }

      System.out.println("the average is " + a / b );

    }
```

}

Comment: Why did you put brackets after the while statement?

Comment: If you give your variables meaningful names rather than `a` and `b`, you will have an easier time finding the bug.

Comment: a will never be less than 1 after the first (positive) input, as new inputs just get added to it.

Comment: Begin by formatting your code nicely and removing unused clutter like the extra braces after the `while`.

Comment: You probably want to define another variable to store the last inputted double instead of checking the accumulative double (a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an input in your `while` check. you need to have another variable called, saying `userInput`:

```
userInput = input.nextDouble();
a += userInput;
}

while(userInput > 0)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding values from input directly to *a*:

```
a+=input.nextDouble();
```

So, if you add values to *a* directly, you can't tell when user typed in 0 and the loop will be terminated only if *a* drops below 0, f.e when user input is 2, 3, -5